# throwing error for flask jwt extended refresh token

Tags: javascript, flask, axios, flask-jwt-extended

I am trying to implement refresh token system in flask_jwt_extended, I followed official documentation. When I try to get new access_token with refresh_token using postman I get the response with new access token. But when I try with axios call it is throwing 401 error saying:

```json
msg: "Missing Authorization Header"
```

my flask code:

```
@app.route("/refresh", methods=["POST"])
@jwt_required(refresh=True)
def refresh():
    identity = get_jwt_identity()
    print(identity)
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=identity)
    return jsonify(access_token=access_token)
    print(access_token)
```

below is my axios api call:

```js
getAPI.post('/refresh', {
          // refresh_token: context.state.refreshToken,
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${context.state.refreshToken}` },
        })
```

axios api call:

```json
{"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsImlhdCI6MTYxNzY0MDcyOCwianRpIjoiNmE3OTYyNjctNjYwMS00ZjQ5LWJmZjEtODUwYjhhMDkyMjgyIiwibmJmIjoxNjE3NjQwNzI4LCJ0eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsInN1YiI6eyJlbWFpbCI6InZlbjMzQGVtYWlsLmNvbSIsImFkZGl0aW9uYWxfY2xhaW1zIjp7InJvbGUiOltbIlVzZXIiXV19fSwiZXhwIjoxNjIwMjMyNzI4fQ.5MoE8DXwO7cCwN5nVC1u1st0cm1LDhBu1nSDb7VJmgg"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'POST' call configuration options for flask_extended should be in third argument. original answer is provided by [github](https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/issues/412#issuecomment-817412637).

```js
getAPI.post('/refresh', {
          {},
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${context.state.refreshToken}` },
        })
```